# customization id in Google Translate python API

Tags: google-api, google-translate, google-api-python-client

I am using Google Translate API for python and I am not sure of the argument `cid` (customization id). Here is the link to the reference: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/python/latest/translate_v2.translations.html

Couldn't find anything useful online.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the provided codesample for translate API, seems like they don't call the list with a cid [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/translate/main.py).

With that in mind, I would simply not use that parameter in my requests. In fact, I never used that parameter in my API calls and it works fine